# jQuery UI show/hide

Tags: jquery

I'm making a sliding div with jQuery UI, but i have a problem.

I have an outer DIV and 2 inner DIV that are left floated. On the first inner DIV i have the sliding effect.

```
<div id="outer">
    Outer Div
    <p><a href="#" id="SlideOut">Slide Out</a></p>
    <p><a href="#" id="SlideIn">Slide In</a></p>

    <div id="inner">inner</div>
    <div id="inner2">inner2</div>
</div>
```

---

```
    $("#SlideOut").click(function(){
    $("#inner").hide("slide",{direction: 'left'},1000);
});

$("#SlideIn").click(function(){
        $("#inner").show("slide",{direction: 'left'},1000);

});
```

The problem is that the second DIV doesn't follow the first div.

It is hard to explain, so here is a fiddle where u can maybe understand better my problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/xFx26/1/

In short, i want that the second inner div will slide together the first inner div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using `animate()` and changing the width, rather than sliding. The slide slides the contents and then hides the actual container. [Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/xFx26/2/)

Code:

```
$("#SlideOut").click(function(){
    $("#inner").animate({width: 0},1000);
});

$("#SlideIn").click(function(){
     $("#inner").animate({width: 200},1000);
});
```

Comment: The content inside the div must slide in/out. I really don't like that.

Comment: Ok this combined with aligning the content to the right, it is the same as sliding it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you need to add inner2 to your jquery like below? Is this what you want?

```
$("#SlideOut").click(function(){
$("#inner").hide("slide",{direction: 'left'},1000);
$("#inner2").hide("slide",{direction: 'left'},1000);
});

$("#SlideIn").click(function(){
    $("#inner").show("slide",{direction: 'left'},1000);
$("#inner2").show("slide",{direction: 'left'},1000);

});
```

Comment: Nope, i do not want to hide the second div, only the position must slide together the first div.

Answer (score 0):

add this in slideout (and the opposite in slidein)

```
    $("#inner2").css("position","relative").animate({left:-200},990,function()  {$(this).css("left","")});
```

but even better put the position:relative in the css & remove from js

Answer (score 0):

You should use `animate` to make you div move from right to left.

```
$("#SlideOut").click(function () {
    $("#inner").hide("slide", {
        direction: 'left'
    }, 1000);
    $("#inner2").animate({
        marginLeft: "-=250px",
    }, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xFx26/5/ Click on SlideOut